# tinymce обрезает url адрес в <img src> после загрузки изрображения

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Использую tinymce 6.1.0, добавил возможность добавления изображений, но `resolve` обрезает часть `https://localhost:5001` и возвращает только относительный путь до файла, а мне нужен абсолютный. Как это можно исправить?

```
var editor = tinymce.init(
{
    selector: '#UpdateViewModel_HtmlContent',
    setup: function (editor)
    {
        editor.on('change', function ()
        {
            editor.save();
        });
    },
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, progress)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(blobInfo.filename(), blobInfo.blob());

            abp.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: abp.appPath + 'api/static/editing/content/image',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res)
                {
                    progress && progress(100);
                    resolve('https://localhost:5001/' + res.url);
                },
                error: function (err)
                {
                    reject('Failed to upload image to server');
                },
                formData: "multipart/form-data"
            });
        });
    },
    plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    file_picker_types: 'image'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `init` метод я добавил следующую опцию:

```
convert_urls: false
```

Вот эти не помогут получать абсолютный путь до файла

```
relative_urls: 0,
remove_script_host: 0
```